# How to run docker-compose up before spring-boot:run goal using Maven?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a SpringBoot application which I can run using `./mvnw spring-boot:run` either from CLI or IDE. I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which has dependent services like **Postgres**, **Localstack** etc.

I want to invoke `docker-compose up` before triggering the `spring-boot:run` goal automatically using Maven.

With Gradle I can simple use `dependsOn` to spin up docker container before running a task.
I couldn't figure out how to tie up this using Maven life cycle phases. Any help?

Comment: I strongly recommend to use https://testcontainers.org for such things cause this is an E2E test....Define via Testcontainers the services you need and run your e2e within your IDE etc...

Comment: I am using testcontainers for tests. But I also want to run application locally which needs DB, AWS etc which I want to run thru docker containers.

Comment: DB can be run in Docker contain so it can be done in Testcontainers ... AWS ? Which parts of it?

Comment: I use S3, SQS services with Localstack docker container.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question, but I already had the same question, and I already find the solution. To do this I add the plugin `exec-maven-plugin` and executed the docker-compose.yml file with it at `validate` phase:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Run Containers</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>docker-compose</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>up --detach</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But you need to put the compose file at project's root folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the folder where the `yaml` is located with `-f`, and in the modern docker, compose is a plugin part of docker itself, meaning that you run it with `docker compose` without the `-`. For example:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>docker</executable>
    <commandlineArgs>compose -f src/test/docker/docker-compose.yaml up -d</commandlineArgs>
</configuration>
```